# Safari getting launched on ios simulator, but not able to get url using driver.get(“”)

Tags: java, selenium, ios-simulator, appium, appium-ios

here is the code:

```
ios simulator is getting launched, safari is also launched and "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub" navigates to the "let's browse" page, but then thats that, not able to navigate to "google.com" page.


    WebDriver driver;
      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
      public void init() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
      capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
      capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 5");
      capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "safari");
      capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.3");
    //capabilities.setCapability("udid", "31C12FD6-8C33-4C58-AD0A-      7AFF9A3DF74B");


      driver=new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),   capabilities);

    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Thread.sleep(4000);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
```

so i am able to launch safari, but not able to navigate to the url,.
Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Getting , 'method is not implemented' webdriver exception now.

Comment: Upgrade your java-client and appium-xcuitest-driver.    https://github.com/appium/java-client .    https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint does not work properly on real devices due to known XCTest limitations.
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9601